# Python function returns PY_VAR1 unexpectedly

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I am expecting my button function to print a number (`minutes_selected`) based on the current value of the Spinner UI element, but the variable is always PY_VAR1:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def get_minutes():
    global minutes_selected
    minutes_selected.get()
    print(mintes_selected)

root = Tk()

minutes_selected = StringVar()
minutes_spinbox = Spinbox(root, from_ = 1, to = 1440, textvariable = minutes_selected).pack()
```

Is there some basic misunderstanding with regards to how variables can be access from within a function?

Comment: this can't possibly be the code that gives you the error. There are syntax errors in the code.

Comment: I had to type the code again as my development machine is airgapped. I failed to faithfully replicate it, but your suggested answer did solve my issue.

Comment: No, could you please provide example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `get` method to get the value of the variable.

Change this:

```
print(mintes_selected)
```

To this:

```
print(minutes_selected.get())
```

Comment: Thank you - I feel very silly now because I would normally have realised this! I put it down to not enough caffeine yet this morning. :)